# Introductory, Independent clauses and participles

Tags: american-english, participles, independent-clauses

> For many people in the US, undergoing a medical procedure can be a stressful, confusing, and sometimes overwhelming ordeal.

I understand that `For...US,` is the introductory phrase and needs the comma. However, `undergoing...ordeal.` is an Independent or a Participle clause ?
Is `undergoing` a participle in this case ?

Comment: 'Undergoing a medical procedure' is an NP.  Taken separately, 'undergoing' is rather a verbal noun. The sentence, "Undergoing a medical procedure can be a stressful, confusing, and sometimes overwhelming ordeal" is a single-clause sentence, which is independent.

Comment: This usage is given the term 'gerund-participial clause' by say CGEL who lump here, and consequently label _undergoing_ here a 'gerund-participle'; followers of ACGEL (Quirk et al) might say 'undergoing' is on the verbo-nominal gradience. The ing-clause contains something 'acted upon'  (_a medical procedure_), showing verbal behaviour of _undergoing_, but acts as a nominal ([undergoing a medical procedure] can be ...).

Comment: Does it make any difference to you whether "undergoing" is a gerund or a participle?  Does it make any difference to you whether "undergoing a medical procedure" is a phrase or a clause?  Are you asking this question to find out whether another comma can be justified?